# Functional setState loses access to event.target.value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have no issues with passing objects to setState. But here is what I am seeing as I test pass a function:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  // ...

  update_input_field = input_event => {
    console.log("input_event.target", input_event.target);

    const update_state = (state_snapshot, props) => {
      return {
        input1: input_event.target.value
      };
    };

    this.setState(update_state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form action="">
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.input1}
          onChange={e => this.update_input_field(e)}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Passing an anonymous function to setState yields the same error as the code above:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
App.update_state
src/App.js:45
  42 | 
  43 | const update_state = (state_snapshot, props) => {
  44 |     return {
> 45 |         input1: input_event.target.value
  46 |     }
  47 | };
  48 |
```

Can someone tell me why the code is losing access to the state variable (input1.target) in the current code sample?

I was able to log the target value inside update_state, but it errs regardless. Therefore I'm thinking the issue is inside the return of that function.

Comment: those answers should resolve your query, let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you for the reference.

Comment: I had the same issue earlier and I solved it the same way as new variable without thinking what could be the reason.

Comment: @MayankShukla cant we pass the input_event to function beforehand const update_state = (state_snapshot, props, input_event) =>

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala, we can pass but it will not be available, because that function will be called by react asynchronously and react will not pass any value to that function for that argument (input_event will be just the argument name). so even if you pass, value will be undefined inside function. clear?